# How can add an object to User Profile in WSO2 IS

Tags: claims-based-identity, claims, wso2-identity-server

Currently, I need add new object to user profile in wsso2 IS as default  which be like the below claim which should choose able by customer.

```
identity {
   "identityId": 23,
   "identityName": " Name Test".
   "Identity Url": "UrlTest"
 }
```

I also read some documents which advice me to add new claims in the below links :

http://pathberiya.blogspot.com/2012/05/claim-management-with-wso2-identity.html

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Claim+Management

But in the document, I can only add specific attribute, not an object.

How can I do in this case ?

I appreciate your help in this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of a attribute is called a complex attribute in SCIM. Currently you cannot have user defined complex attribute types apart from the default complex attributes supported, e.g. address, in WSO2 Identity Server (neither in 5.1.0 nor 5.2.0).

Comment: oh, currently, I am using SOAP not SCIM :(